# Proof of Cauchy-Schwartz inequality with dot product and euclidean norm

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have some problems on understanding the proof of **Cauchy-Schwartz inequality** from my textbook:

> Given $\textbf{x,y} \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \vert \textbf{x}^T \textbf{y} \vert \le \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert_2 \cdot \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert_2$

the proof:

> given $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we can observe that : $$\begin{align} 0 \le \Vert \textbf{x} + \lambda \textbf{y} \Vert_2^2  
> & =  \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i + \lambda y_i)^2 \\ 
> & =  \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 + 2 \lambda x_i y_i + \lambda^2 y_i^2)  \\
> & =  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + 2\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i + \lambda^2 \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 \\
> & =  \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 + 2 \lambda \textbf{x}^T \textbf{y} + \vert \lambda \vert^2 \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert^2_2
> \end{align}$$
>   if $\textbf{x}^T\textbf{y} = 0$ then the thesis is surely true.
>   Instead, if $\textbf{x}^T\textbf{y} \ne 0$, then we can consider:
>   $$\lambda = - \frac{\Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2}{\textbf{x}^T\textbf{y}}$$
>   therefore we have:
>   $$\begin{align} 0 \le \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 - 2\Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 + \frac{\Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^4_2}{\vert \textbf{x}^T \textbf{y} \vert^2} \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert^2_2 
> & = -\Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 \frac{\Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^4_2}{\vert \textbf{x}^T \textbf{y} \vert^2} \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert^2_2 \\ 
> & = \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 \left ( -1 + \frac{\Vert \textbf{x}\Vert^2_2 \Vert \textbf{y}\Vert^2_2  }{ \vert \textbf{x}^T \textbf{y} \vert^2 }\right )    \end{align}$$
>   we can deduce that :
>   $$\Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert^2_2 - \vert \textbf{x}^T \textbf{y} \vert^2 \ge 0 $$ 
>   and then the thesis follows easily.

---

There are some questions I want to post here:

1) why immediately is it observed that $0 \le \Vert \textbf{x} + \lambda \textbf{y} \Vert_2^2$, from where we can deduce that observation?

2) when it says << if $\textbf{x}^T\textbf{y} = 0$ then the thesis is surely true. >> for "thesis", does it mean the expression of above proposition?:

> $$\vert \textbf{x}^T \textbf{y} \vert \le \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert_2 \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert_2$$

but if I substitute in the last passage:

$$\begin{align}& =  \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 + 2 \lambda \textbf{x}^T \textbf{y} + \vert \lambda \vert^2 \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert^2_2 \\
& = \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 + 2 \lambda 0 + \vert \lambda \vert^2 \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert^2_2 \\
& = \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2 + \vert \lambda \vert^2 \Vert \textbf{y} \Vert^2_2
\end{align}$$

I do not obtain the $\Vert \textbf{x} \Vert_2 \Vert \textbf{x} \Vert_2$ of the thesis of the proposition.

3) why considering the $\lambda$ in that way?

> Instead, if $\textbf{x}^T\textbf{y} \ne 0$, then we can consider
>   $$\lambda = - \frac{\Vert \textbf{x} \Vert^2_2}{\textbf{x}^T\textbf{y}}$$

Please, can you help me to understand better? Many thanks!

Comment: (1) From the definition of inner product and the norm induced from it $\|x\|^2=(x,x)\geq0$. (2) *Thesis* is what you want to prove, yes. (3) If you look at that polynomial in $\lambda$, which is quadratic, that specific value is the vertex of the parabola, at which you attain the smallest value. Since you know that all values are $\geq0$, it follows that the smallest value is also $\geq0$. You choose the smallest value to get a result as tight as possible, and also symmetric in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: That last part of the proof is more natural if instead of telling which value of $\lambda$ to take, you complete the square, or try to minimize the quadratic polynomial by taking derivatives with respect to $\lambda$. But some authors prefer to write math like a magic show instead of experiment and deduction, which is how mathematics is really created.

Comment: @user647486 can explain better the (1)? note that I have corrected the typo in the statement.

Comment: There is no change in the explanation of (1). By definition of inner product $(x,x)\geq0$. Ah! In your notation and particular case of finite dimension $x^Tx\geq0$ just because that is a sum of squares of real numbers (the coordinates of $x$). Then $\|x\|^2=x^Tx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) This is from the definition of a norm; namely, they are nondegenerate.
(2) The RHS is non-negative (again by nondegeneracy) and so if the LHS is 0, then the inequality must be satisfied. 
(3) This choice of $\lambda$ makes the arithmetic come out like you want. He proves a general inequality and then picks a specific $\lambda$ so that the more general inequality will reduce to the desired inequality.

Comment: in (3) what is the way to follow to deduce that $\lambda$? I tried to obtain $\lambda$ from the previous inequality passage but without success.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an intuitive way to explain how to come up with that $\lambda$. I imagine if you did the computation he wrote up, but just left $\lambda$ in the equation, then you'd come to a point where you should see that that choice of $\lambda$ will give the necessary cancellation to properly simplify the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

1. It follows from the fact the a norm is always greater than or equal to $0$.
2. The statement of the Cauchy-Schwarz equality is not what you wrote. It is $\lvert x^Ty\rvert\leqslant\lVert x\rVert_2\lVert y\rVert_2$. This obviously holds if $x^Ty=0$.
3. I suppose that my previous reamrk explains this too.